# How do I add foreach iteration support to my own collection class in C++?

Tags: c++, foreach, iteration

I have created a C++ implementation of a collection type.
I would like to add iteration support so that developers may use the "for each" statement on it.
How can I do that?

Comment: c++ has no foreach statement. There's a type of for loop in C++11 that does a foreach - do you mean that? Do you just mean so it can be used in a for loop? Or are you looking at BOOST_FOREACH?

Comment: I think that Visual Studio 2008 has a foreach implemented

Comment: I saw it here... didn't realize it was only in C++ .Net.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177203.aspx

Damn you Microsoft!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard idiom is : expose types `iterator` and `const_iterator` and provide minimum two functions namely, `begin()` and `end()` as:

```
template</*.....*/>
class Collection
{
 public:
     typedef /*...*/ iterator;
     typedef /*...*/ const_iterator;

     iterator begin();
     iterator end();

     const_iterator begin() const;
     const_iterator end() const;
};
```

Once you implement these, your collection can be used in `std::for_each`, and in a lot other algorithmic functions which are defined in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: @Che: that's standard C++. foreach would be C++/CLI…

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the `for_each` algorithm, you just need something that represents the standard `begin` and `end` container methods: iterators to the first and one-past-end points in your logical container.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the STL's `for_each` algorithm, you just need to define `begin()` and `end()` like the STL containers do.

If you mean C++0x's range-based for loop, then you can just do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;

// very very simple container class
class Cont {
public:
    Cont() {}
    typedef char* iterator;
    iterator begin() {return arr;}
    iterator end() {return &arr[200];}

private:
    char arr[200];
};

void setit(char &it) {
    it = 'a';
} 
// iterator must provide ++ operation for for_each algorithm (char* in this example works this way)
int main() {
    Cont c;
    for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), setit);
    copy(c.begin(), c.end(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, ","));
    return 0;
}
```